# Java / Replace all Quotation mark

Tags: java, regex

I to replace all Quotation mark in sentence to some word.

Input: `hello (and "How" are you"?")`

Output: `hello (and WORD are youWORD)`

I try this is Java: `mySentence.replaceAll("[\"].*[\"]", "WORD");`

But nothing happens. How I can resolve it?

Comment: `But nothing happens.` That's probably because you didn't assign a variable to the replace. `.replaceAll` does not change the variable `mySentence` but creates a new one, and you won't see anything if you don't assign it. Is it possible to have escaped quotes in your input string by the way? Like `hello (and "How \"are\"" you"?")`

Comment: @Jerry: Yes, you right.

Comment: Okay. Do you know if you have escaped quotes? (seems you didn't see my edit in the comment above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
String replaced = mySentence.replaceAll("\".*?\"", "WORD");
```

Or better:

```
String replaced = mySentence.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"", "WORD");
//=> hello (and WORD are youWORD)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could easilly do this by converting a string in a character array.

```
string s= "and "?" how are you "?" "

char[] arr= s.toCharArray();

for(int i=0; i>arr.length; arr++)
{
    if(arr[i].isLetter() == false)
    {
    arr[i]= ' ';
    }
}
```