# JAVA replace All except strings starting with '

Tags: java, methods, replaceall

I have a messed up String Like:

`String text= "'xhxyxhzx'xcxz" ";`

and I want to replaceAll() the other strings with ***empty*** except the one starting with `'`

Something like this:

```
String cleartext = ""; 
if (text.contains("'"))
        cleartext = text.replaceAll("[text.startingWith("'a-z" + "'0-9")]", "");        
         out.println(cleartext);
```

So the output is `'h' 'e' 'll' 'o'`

Note: I just found it kinda possible to make it with the replace method but if there are other ways that this can be achieved I don't mind. **MASSIVE Thank you!**

Comment: `except the one starting with '` ... can you explain what this means?

Comment: `text.replaceAll("[text.startingWith("'a-z" + "'0-9")]", "");`  What did you expect from this line?

Comment: Why do you "want to replaceAll"? Is this a requirement, or just an idea of yours? [What is the _real_ problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) that you're working on?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: where did you get this messed-up string from, and will you get more of these from the same source? Is there a well-written specification on these messed-up strings?

Comment: in your example messed-up string, after `..x,,xl` there are **three** single-quotes, which would actually mean your output will be `'h' 'e' 'll' 'l;2' 'waaa' 'qcz' .....`. when implementing a solution like Farhan's.

Comment: @tim so I want every string being it number letter or symbol inside the 'x' to be outputed not the other ones

Comment: @KunLun that line is only a example i wrote now i expect a sinilar code that replaces everything except strings starting with  the ' char being them letters from a-z or numbers 0-9

Comment: Roland no as stated above I just want whatever solution it exists to get that output  doesnt really matter im making this for a personal project, and yes ill be getting loats of strings like that generated from another app output in a .txt file. Yes there is heres an example : 2018-11-22 08:30:21,311: 'a'

Comment: @cashbee its just an bad example every string is like this : 2018-11-22 08:30:21,311: 'a'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java / Replace all Quotation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812170/java-replace-all-quotation-mark)

Answer (score 3):

According to me we can do one thing. I hope you don't mind a no code answer.

1. Split the string through the character ' and place it into array of string. For example String "h'e'll'o'." becomes h , e , ll , o , .
2. Disregard all odd number indexes. The string in the even index would be the one inside the ' character. Example in above is "e , o"
3. Output the string array even indexes or create a new array by step 2.

Comment: This seems a clever way to implement the OP's request.

Comment: Sorry i took a bad example but the strings will be exactly like this:  2018-11-22 08:30:21,311: 'a' and I dont think this method wich ofc is very smart, wont be very efficient

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'[a-z0-9]+'");

private String function(final String input) {
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(matcher.group());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

However, I'm not really sure about the rules you want to apply in order to get the expected result. Ex: `"'''" => "'"` ?

Comment: You can leave out the `[^']*` at the beginning of the regular expression since you are using `find` in a loop. Thereby, `group(1)` becomes equivalent to a simple `group()`.